# Constant mass flux in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

OK so I am having a conceptual crisis about Hydrodynamics.

1) Since mass should be conserved, is $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$ ?

2) But I know that the formula $\rho_1u_1A_1 = \rho_2u_2A_2$ exists... and doesn't that mean the mass flux is conserved? Where does this formula come from?

3) How can we derive an expression for $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$ from the continuity equation  $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{u})=0$

Comment: In regards to 2), should the right side have 2 as subscripts instead of 1?

Comment: I actually found an answer, should I delete this question?

Comment: Why not write up your solution as an answer for others who might have the same question?

Comment: Kyle, your description says you are an expert in hydrodynamics. What do you think of the last part of my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so in the end I found an answer:

$\textbf{Derivation}$

Mass is conserved, so $$\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$$

But $$m = \iiint \rho(\mathbf{r}, t)d^3\mathbf{r} $$ so that $$ \frac{dm}{dt} = \iiint \frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t}d^3\mathbf{r} = 0$$.
From the continuity equation $$ \frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot(\rho\mathbf{u})$$.
So $$ \iiint \frac{\partial \rho(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t}d^3\mathbf{r} = 0 \quad\text{implies} \quad -\iiint \nabla \cdot(\rho\mathbf{u}) d^3\mathbf{r}=0$$ which using Stokes' theorem becomes $$ \iint \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\;\;\;\subset\!\supset  (\rho\mathbf{u})\cdot d\mathbf{S} = 0$$

Applying this to a flow like the one in the diagram[image]

so that the velocity is parallel to the cross sectional areas ($A_1$ and $A_2$) and there is no vertical component of the velocity in the top and bottom surfaces.

Assuming the density and the velocity are constants over that area (at a fixed $x$), the integral becomes:
$$ \rho_1A_1\mathbf{v_1} = \rho_2A_2\mathbf{v_2} $$

$\textbf{Possible second derivation}$

There should also be another way of deriving this:

Starting once again from $$\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$$ and using  the definition of a convective derivative (or *Lagrangian* derivative) $$ \frac{d}{dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)$$ where $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the *Eulerian* derivative, we get $$ \frac{\partial m}{\partial t} = -(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)m $$

No idea how to get to the required equation though.
Any pointers?

Comment: If you note that $\nabla\cdot\left(m\mathbf{u}\right)=\mathbf u\cdot\nabla m+m\nabla\cdot\mathbf u$. Then if the flow is incompressible, $\nabla\cdot\mathbf u=0$, you can turn your RHS to $\mathbf u \cdot\nabla m=\nabla\cdot(m\mathbf u)$. Then use the same integration trick: $m=\int \rho\,dV$ where $dV$ is arbitrary thus it must hold for $\rho$.

Comment: Exactly that's the point: incompressibility.
I did not assume it in the first derivation, so why do I need to assume it here?

Comment: I'd argue that the reason is because the [convective derivative assumes incompressibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow#Difference_between_incompressible_flow_and_material). Others may not appreciate my assertion, but it's how I view it.

Comment: The convective derivative of the density = 0 implies incompressibility, as I can see why (density has can change in space but has to remain constant in time).
But here I have the convective derivative of the mass.

Comment: Well actually now that I think about it would it make sense to have $\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$ with a compressible flow? Would mass just pop out of nowhere / disappear?

Comment: it shouldn't, I mean we can have mass building up (increased $\rho$) somewhere provided that $\rho$ is decreasing somewhere else

Comment: You can have sources and losses of mass. Think about water flowing through two pipes; mass could either come in or leave through the 2nd pipe.

Comment: ok but still I didn't assume incompressiiblity of the flow in my answer, how come I need to assume it here in order to get the same answer?

Comment: My 2nd comment answers your question: the convective derivative assumes incompressibility. Otherwise, your relation would be $D_t\rho=-m\nabla\cdot\mathbf u$, as is stated a few lines above the link I provided.

Comment: $m$ does not depend on $x$, it depends on a domain over which you integrate $\rho$. Therefor $\nabla m$ has no meaning.

You can pick one that is entrained by the velocity, in which case $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$, or one which is fixed, in which case $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is equal to the incoming flux.

Comment: sorry I don't see what you mean, could you try to explain it again please?